# TSQL Random Select with Selective Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My database has 5 categories in table "category".
I also have a table called "items", where each item has unique Id and a category Id FK.

I need to randomly select 10 items from 1 category.

This would not be problem if there was only 1 category. But table "items" stores categories id in non-sequential order.

The random select statement below works and is able to generate random IDs within a range. But how can I generate 10 random IDs that belong to the same category?

```
Declare @maxRandomValue tinyint = 100
    , @minRandomValue tinyint = 0;

Select Cast(((@maxRandomValue + 1) - @minRandomValue) 
    * Rand() + @minRandomValue As tinyint) As 'randomNumber';
```

Defintions:

```
Table Categories
ID INT
Desc Varchar(100)

Table Items
ID Int
CategoryID Int (fk)
Desc Varchar(100)
```

Comment: take a look at [this MSDN article on random sampling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175776%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.MyTable ORDER BY NEWID();` always works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Use

- a WHERE to filter to a category
- NEWID to randomise rows
- TOP to limit you to 10 items

So:

```
SELECT TOP 10
   *
FROM
   Items
WHERE
   CategoryID = @whatever
ORDER BY
   NEWID()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select top 10 * from items where categoryid = 1 order by newid()
```